# In a file/array, search for hash key, and replace it with the hash value, do this for all hash keys/values

Tags: perl, search, hash, replace, bioinformatics

I've searched around the site and surprisingly I can't seem to find something that will work for my particular problem.  So I figured I'd post it and see how some of you more experienced programmers can address with problem.

I have a spreadsheet like text file (many lines with tab delimited columns), that I would like to search through for certain labels (ex scaffold1253.1_size81005.6.32799_7496) and replace them with more simplified labels (ex scaffold1253.1a). These labels are only in the first column of the text file. I've already written the script such that I have a hash with the old labels as keys corresponding to the new labels as their respective values. This hash has about 26000 lines. So essentially I'd like to take the hash keys 1 by 1, search for them in the text file, and replace them with their respective hash values.

I have a pretty good server availible so if its too complicated to make it first column specific to speed up the process then thats ok.

THis is what I have so far:

```
 use warnings;  



$gtf = './Hc_genome/Hc_rztk_1+2+8+9.augustus.gtf'; 
    open(FASTAFILE2, $gtf);
    @gtfarray = <FASTAFILE2>;
    #print @gtfarray;


my %hash;
while (<>)
{
   chomp;
   my ($key, $val) = split /\t/;
   $hash{$key} .= exists $hash{$key} ? ",$val" : $val;
}

#print %hash;

while (my ($find, $replace) = each %hash) {
    foreach (@gtfarray){
        $_ =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
        push @newgtf, $_;   
    }
}
print @newgtf;
```

This code doesn't seem to work as it doesn't complete. I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the foreach loop structure. Sorry I don't know of any other way to do this. Does anyone have a better way to run through this file and conduct the replacement?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,

Andrew

@DVK

Here is the full script with your mods that runs into syntax errors with your while loop, any idea why it's not accepting it? Thanks again!

```
use warnings;  

$gtf = './Hc_genome/Hc_rztk_1+2+8+9.augustus.gtf'; 
    open(FASTAFILE2, $gtf);

my %hash;
while (<>){
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split /\t/;
    $hash{$key} .= exists $hash{$key} ? ",$val" : $val;
}


while $line (<FASTAFILE2>){
    my @fields = split(/\t/, $line);
    # If you only care about first column, don't need the foreach loop below;
    #    just do the loop insides on $fields[0]
    foreach my $field (@fields) {
        $field = $hash{$field} if exists $hash{$field};
        print $outfile "$field\t"; # Small bug - will print training \t
    }
    print $outfile "\n"
}

__END__
```

Here is the syntax error:
perl gtf_mod2.pl <./Hc_genome/header_file.txt
syntax error at gtf_mod2.pl line 14, near "while $line "
syntax error at gtf_mod2.pl line 23, near "}"
Execution of gtf_mod2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: You have to put `$line` inside the parens like `while (my $line = <FASTAFILE2>)`

Answer (score 1):

You exhaust your file the first time through your loop using the initial `$find` and `$replace` key/value pair.

There are two potential solutions:

1. Open the file for reading during *each* iteration of your while loop (expensive)
2. Move the foreach loop to the outside of the while and iterate the *hash* each time (less expensive)

example:

```
REPLACE:
for my $line (@gtfarray) {
   while(my ($find, $replace) = each %hash) {
      if($line =~ s/$find/$replace/g) {
         push @newgtf, $line;
         next REPLACE; # skip to next iteration
      }
   }
   # if there was no replacement, push the old line
   push @newgtf, $line
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm running it right now. The gtf file that is being modified is ~315000 lines long so it will probably take a while. I'll let you know how it turns out. I'm also trying the suggestion below as they did it the opposite way as he suggested with a large text file it should take less time.

Answer (score 1):

How big is the file that you are replacing the first column in?

If it's >50,000 lines, you are better off doing the **reverse**:

- Iterate through hash file once, and store that hash in memory
- Iterate through main file **once**, and for every line, for every column, find that value in the memorized hash, replace with hash value if found, and write.

In other words, remove the first `@gtfarray = <FASTAFILE2>;` and replace your last while loop with:

```
while my $line (<FASTAFILE2>) {
    my @fields = split(/\t/, $line);
    # If you only care about first column, don't need the foreach loop below;
    #    just do the loop insides on $fields[0]
    foreach my $field (@fields) {
        $field = $hash{$field} if exists $hash{$field};
        print $outfile "$field\t"; # Small bug - will print training \t
    }
    print $outfile "\n";
}
```

NOTE: I'm making an assumption that the fields contain FULL contents of your hash keys (e.g. your data file would contain a field with "scaffold1253.1_size81005.6.32799_7496" but NOT a field with "XYZscaffold1253.1_size81005.6.32799_7496___IOU").

If that assumption is wrong and you really DO need to run a regex because your scaffold strings may be contained in longer strings, there may still be a better solution aside from running O(N*M) regexes: if your scaffold strings are all of a certain well defined format (e.g. "scaffoldNNNNN.NNN_sizeNNNNN.NNN.NNNN_NNNN"), what you need to do then is:

- For each line of data file, run a single regex finding that pattern, with the entire pattern inside a capture group parenthesis:

  ```
  @matches = ($line =~ m/(scaffold\d+\.\d+_size\d+\.\d+\.\d+_\d+/g );
  ```
- Then, look up every value of @matches array in the hash. If found, run ONLY the matches as a s/// regex.

Comment: He said the sought value to replace is in the first column, I think, so I think the `foreach` loop would be unnecessary - just check `$fields[0]`.

Comment: @ChrisCharley - I'm confused, whether it's first column of data file or of hash file that he meant. Good point.

Comment: Sorry, yes it's the first column (columns separated by tabs) of the data file that contains the old labels which need to be replaced by the new labels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer DVK, Yes the text/gtf file is very large (~315000 lines) so I'm guessing your idea of iterating trough the hash would be faster. I seem to be running into some syntax errors when I try to run the block of code you posted above, specifically on the first line of the while loop and the last line of the while loop, there seems to be compilation errors. Ill post the full script below.

Comment: DVK, if you don't mind helping me out a bit more please see the edit to my above post to see the syntax error that I got from the while loop. Any idea why it might be yielding this? Thanks again!

Comment: @amrezans - if you have a new problem, you should simply post it as a new question so as to not confuse people reading later :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a job for [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile)?  Assuming, that is, the data file could be operated on as an array.

```
use Tie::File; 

my $file = "./Hc_genome/Hc_rztk_1+2+8+9.augustus.gtf"; 

tie @lines, 'Tie::File', $file or die ;
for (@lines) {
 s/Oldlabel/NewLable/g;   # Change this to fit
}

untie @lines ;
```

`Tie::File` does a bunch of tricks to keep the "in place " changes to the file  memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437838/simplifying-elements-of-a-list-array-and-then-adding-incremental-identifiers-a-b), wouldn't it be more simple to create the shortened 'id' while reading the file. Then you would have no need of the other file where you get your hash?

Here is the (untested) code below. (would need to direct the print statements to an output file on the command line or open a file for writing in your script).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $gtf = './Hc_genome/Hc_rztk_1+2+8+9.augustus.gtf';
open my $FASTAFILE2, "<", $gtf or die "Unable to open '$gtf' for reading. $!";

my %seen;

while (<$FASTAFILE2>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id, $val) = split /\t/, $_, 2;

    # copy $id to $prefix and
    # remove everything after '.1' in $prefix
    (my $prefix = $id) =~ s/\.1\K.*//; 

    if ($seen{$id}) {
        ++$seen{$id};
    }
    else {
        $seen{$id} = 'a';   
    }
    print "$prefix$seen{$id}\t$val\n";
}

close $FASTAFILE2 or die "Unable to close '$gtf' from reading. $!";
```

Comment: Hmm, so the thing is, I still need the file created through the code in the last post on its own. But also, some of the scaffolds in the file used in the previous post are skipped in the text/gtf file here. So I believe this would cause some scaffolds to be labeled with an earlier letter in the alphabet than they should be. So I had to import the proper labels with the hash. Essentially this gtf file contains annotated genes within the genome of the previous post, and is missing some labels/scaffolds simply because there are some scaffolds with no annotated genes! Hope that makes sense ;)